# Showing variable names after exponentiating output glm R

Tags: r, glm

I am sure there is a way to do this but I am not sure how to show the variable names for my output along with my exponentiated results for a relative risk output for a project I am working on. Below includes some sample code. It is probably relatively easy, but I am not sure how to extract the variable name/factor level column so that it is side-by-side with the risk ratio outputs so that I do not have to look at the numbered rows from the prior output and compare with my exponentiated output. The first column isn't truly stored as a column, from what I can tell. Basically, for my output I want the first one to say "(Intercept) 0.24 (0.06-1.01)" and so on. Thanks!!!

```
> cov.m1 <- vcovHC(sexrr_modadj_mm, type = "HC0")
> std.err <- sqrt(diag(cov.m1))
> q.val <- qnorm(0.975)
> r.est <- cbind(
+   Estimate = coef(sexrr_modadj_mm)
+   , "Robust SE" = std.err
+   , z = (coef(sexrr_modadj_mm)/std.err)
+   , "Pr(>|z|) "= 2 * pnorm(abs(coef(sexrr_modadj_mm)/std.err), lower.tail = FALSE)
+   , LL = coef(sexrr_modadj_mm) - q.val  * std.err
+   , UL = coef(sexrr_modadj_mm) + q.val  * std.err
+ )
> r.est
                                                   Estimate    Robust SE            z     Pr(>|z|)             LL
(Intercept)                                   -1.430923e+00 0.7337880617  -1.95004986  5.117018e-02 -2.869121e+00
PrimaryAnesthesiaTypeGeneral                   5.283219e-02 0.5460422343   0.09675477  9.229211e-01 -1.017391e+00
PrimaryAnesthesiaTypeMonitor Anesthesia Care   1.874183e+00 0.9023864714   2.07691834  3.780910e-02  1.055380e-01
PrimaryAnesthesiaTypeNeuraxial Nerve Block    -2.096085e+00 1.1418850877  -1.83563536  6.641160e-02 -4.334138e+00
PrimaryAnesthesiaTypePeripheral Nerve Block   -1.315466e+01 0.6931926700 -18.97691303  2.646985e-80 -1.451329e+01
PrimaryAnesthesiaTypeRegional                 -7.875437e-02 0.4793121244  -0.16430706  8.694894e-01 -1.018189e+00
PrimaryBlockEpidural                           2.211594e-01 0.1356256444   1.63066036  1.029620e-01 -4.466202e-02

> paste(round(exp(r.est[,1]), digits = 2), " (", round(exp(r.est[,5]), digits = 2), "-", round(exp(r.est[,6]), digits = 2), ")", sep = "")

 [1] "0.24 (0.06-1.01)"    "1.05 (0.36-3.07)"    "6.52 (1.11-38.2)"    "0.12 (0.01-1.15)"    "0 (0-0)"            
 [6] "0.92 (0.36-2.36)"    "1.25 (0.96-1.63)"    "0 (0-0)"             "0 (0-0)"             "0 (0-0)"
```

Comment: `paste(round(...  the rest of your code ...)) |> setNames(row.names(r.est))` will take the row names from `r.est` and apply them to your vector.

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. Maybe just share `dput(r.est)` because it doesn't really seem to matter what the model was if you are just working with the matrix output.

Comment: If you like `dplyr` or working with data frames, you might find the `broom` package a more convenient way to extract and work with your coefficient estimates.

Answer (score 3):

You can apply names to a vector with `setNames`. Seems like you want to apply the row names from your `r.est` matrix, so this should work:

```
paste(
  round(exp(r.est[,1]), digits = 2),
  " (",
  round(exp(r.est[,5]), digits = 2),
  "-",
  round(exp(r.est[,6]), digits = 2),
  ")", sep = ""
) |> 
  setNames(row.names(r.est))
```

I find your code pretty hard to read, often `sprintf` is cleaner for "fill-in-the-blank" style string construction. And the format string `%.2f` will round to 2 decimal places without another function call. We can also use column names to make things clearer. Something like this (though I'm confused becuase the `r.est` you show seems to only have 5 columns yet you reference the 6th... I guess UL didn't make it into your question.)

```
sprintf(
  "%.2f (%.2f-%.2f)",
  exp(r.est[, "Estimate"]), 
  exp(r.est[, "LL"]), 
  exp(r.est[, "UL"])
) |>
  setNames(row.names(r.est))
```

I'd also suggest looking at the `broom` package to get everything into nice data frames.